# Clarity popover move top,left when you click outside signpost/tooltip instead of disappearing

Tags: javascript, angular, sharepoint, vmware-clarity

The clairty popover (tooltips,signpost,dropdown) moves left of the screen instead of closing.

Clicking the close button, closes it fine.

The angular app is hosted inside a sharepoint aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say whats going on without seeing any code or a working reproduction of your issue. Here is a simple Signpost that closes when clicking outside of it.

```
        <clr-signpost>
            <clr-signpost-content *clrIfOpen [clrPosition]="'right-bottom'">
                <h3>Default Signpost</h3>
                <p>Position: <code class="clr-code">right-bottom</code></p>
            </clr-signpost-content>
        </clr-signpost
```

You can find the working code in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-signpost-clicking-question). If your issue is not helped with this answer, fork that code and reproduce your issue and share the StackBlitz link to your fork. I can then use that to diagnose whats going on for your use case.